# How do I convert a DSN connection to a DSN connection exactly in Access 2007?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a MS Access database that I need to connect to a MySQL db.  I can't be sure what PC the Access db will be opened on and it must work on any office pc that's used.  I believe I need to create a DSN-less connection to do this.  I created the linked table with a DSN but of course, it doesn't work for anyone else.

I've done some googling and what I get back tells me how to put a connection string in the code.  I don't have any code here, no script.  If I have to write something in the code somewhere, where does that need to go exactly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Doug Steele has provided code](http://web.archive.org/web/20111016195200/http://www.accessmvp.com/djsteele/DSNLessLinks.html) to do this for you. I use it in all my SQL Server/ODBC applications. I program on a machine with a DSN defined, and when I add a linked table/view using the DSN, I immediately run his code to convert it to a DSN-less connection. It works great.